# Actual Storage Load of a Cassandra node

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Is there any way to get the actual data size stored on a node?
The nodetool outputs afaik only the compressed data size.
Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `nodetool cfstats <keyspace>`?  That should break it down on a per column family basis (for each column family in the specified keyspace).  And it should give you more detail on space usage.

```
aploetz@ubuntu:/var/lib/cassandra/data$ nodetool cfstats products
Keyspace: products
    Read Count: 3515
    Read Latency: 0.4077462304409673 ms.
    Write Count: 5434
    Write Latency: 0.04547313213102686 ms.
    Pending Tasks: 0
            Table: itemmaster
            SSTable count: 3
            Space used (live), bytes: 1156013
            Space used (total), bytes: 1266953
            SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.2963641232834859
            ...
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I´m looking for! :)